# Spring MVC to send responsebody object to ajax post gives 406 error

Tags: json, ajax, spring-mvc, http-headers, jackson

There are similar links but I haven't found any solution to work for me, so I was wondering if someone could give me a working example for my scenario.  I am doing an ajax get to retrieve data from the server side, so I can create charts dynamically on the client side.  Do I need to include MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter?  If that's the answer can someone provide an example i can follow for that?

Java:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getReportData.html", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody Reports getReport1Data(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    System.out.println("Report 1 Page GET Method");

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("report1");  

    if((Reports)request.getSession().getAttribute(USER_SESSION_REPORTS) != null){
        reports = (Reports)request.getSession().getAttribute(USER_SESSION_REPORTS);
        System.out.println("--------> Report 1 Page with session data");
        return reports;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("--------> Report 1 Page with NO session data");
    }
    mv.addObject("report1", reports.getReport1());

    return null;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function getData(){
$.ajax({
    url: "getReportData.html",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: JSON,
    success: function(report1){
        console.log("success: " + report1.utilRatio.decRatio);
    },
    error: function(report1){
        console.log("error: " + report1.utilRatio.decRatio);
    }
});
```

}

Response Headers:
**Content-Language**: "en",
**Content-Length**: "1110"
**Content-Type**: "text/html;charset=utf-8"
**Server**: "Apache-Coyote/1.1"

Request Headers:
**Accept**: "*/*"
**Accept-Language**: "en-US,en;q=0.5"
**Accept-Encoding**: "gzip,deflate"
**Content-Type**: "application/json"
**X-Requested-With**: "XMLHttpRequest"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your request headers are wrong. You can remove the contentType setting since you are not sending data to the server and change dataType to the string value "json" instead of the variable JSON.

Also, your response headers are wrong. Just make sure you are always returning a Reports object. And you probably want to remove the html extension from that endpoint since you're just returning an object.

Comment: unfortunately i'm still getting a 406 error after doing the above:
1) only keep dataType, and made it "json"
2) always returned Reports object in every scenario
3) removed all modelAndView objects

.... still getting 406 which is frustrating, this is the only part i need to understand/get and i'd be done :(

Comment: these are the libraries i've included through maven, maybe I'm missing a jackson library i need?

<!--  JSON Processing  -->
    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version>
 </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

spring uses @ResponseBody annotaion for returning data as json .it will implicitly call the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter .so you need to use it.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getjson", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@Transactional
public void getJson(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("type") String type)
        throws DatatypeConfigurationException, IOException, JSONException {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
              List<Chart> chart=myService.getChart();
                        if (Chart.size()>0) {
                json.put("status", "SUCCESS");
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                for (Chart chartData: chart) {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                    object.put("id", chartData.getRaasiId());
                    object.put("name", chartData.getName());
                    array.put(object);
                }
                json.put("options", array);
            }
        }
    } 
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    System.out.println("response======" + json.toString());
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(json.toString());
}
```

============
        on the html

```
             jQuery
                .ajax({
                    url : controllerUrl,
                    dataType : 'text',
                    processData : false,
                    contentType : false,
                    type : 'GET',
                    success : function(response) {
    success : function(response) {
                        marker = JSON.stringify(response);
                        json = jQuery.parseJSON(marker);
                        json = JSON.parse(json);
                        alert(json.status);
                        }
                });
```

for reference:
https://rwehner.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/2-ways-to-create-json-response-for-ajax-request-in-spring3/